# Bitbucket link on my profile?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I love the look of the new profile page, and it's great that it's got a field for your GitHub account, but what about us poor Bitbucket users?  I know I can't expect Stack Exchange to support every source control host under the sun, but including Bitbucket would be great.

**Edit:** I abandoned Bitbucket after they dropped support for Mercurial. Not much point in using it anymore, it's just a GitHub clone now.

Comment: Having one makes sense, so  they just chose the biggest. If they add more, people will also ask to add Facebook,  etc.

Comment: Agreed, I get why GitHub got first treatment.  But BitBucket hosts a lot of code too (mine, in particular ;) ) and it'd be nice to either provide more choices or document why SE only supports certain hosts.

Comment: Didn't you know? Monocultures are great for programmers! Let's make sure everyone uses the same single site in each niche!

Comment: Woah! You mean to tell me that there are other people that like Bitbucket better than GitHub? Hi fellow Bitbucket-ers! It's really unfortunate that Bitbucket's superiority is overshadowed by the popularity of GitHub.